# Ctrl+click isn't opening links in my VS Code with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, windows-11

I can't open urls in my files in VS Code any more. Everything works to suggest the functionality is still there except for the part where it opens a link in my browser. The link changes color, and a popover shows:

[image: screenshot of ctrl+click]

But nothing happens when I click?

Comment: I get the same error at window.open and my control click works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed my default browser to Firefox and it works. So it must be a problem with Chrome.

I tried the following debug steps, taken from a GitHub discussion. <sup>1</sup>

- In VS Code, **≡** > **Help** > **Toggle Developer Tools**.
- In the top menu, select **Console**.
- In the bottom/main pane, type (or paste) `window.open("http://www.bing.com")`
- Hit <kbd>Enter ↵</kbd>.

If the above steps don't open Bing in Chrome, try switching your default browser to Firefox, and then do the steps again.

Others have reported that when switching the default browser back to Chrome, 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[click]</kbd> on a link in VS Code now opens the link in Chrome, just as it should.

---

<sup>1</sup>
When I tried the steps, I got *Error: Prevented call to window.open(). Use IOpenerService instead!*

Comment: I'm afraid I never figured out why it wouldn't work in Chrome. I just switched to Firefox instead. I guess we're at the same place @Henke

Comment: I don't know what's causing the problem, but a new version of Visual Studio Code, 1.86.1, was announced today.
I installed it, then switched my default browser from Firefox back to Google Chrome, and tried the `window.open("http://www.bing.com")` trick suggested in this answer.
It now works – bing opens in Google Chrome.
And Ctrl + click also works.
Whether it's *permanently* working remains to be seen.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multi cursor mode enabled it doens't work anymore:

[image: mode]

If it says go to alt click it is enabled.

Edit: I just noticed this isn't the solution for you. This might be the solution for other people if you have this:

[image]

Here is a second solution. This needs to be enabled:

[image: solution 2]

Thirth solution:

Change your standard browser to a different one and back

Comment: I tried toggling these settings but no joy. Good idea though - thanks!

Comment: @JimmyTheCode did you fix it yet? If not you can try disabling your extensions.

Comment: I'm afraid not. I've disabled all of my extensions in VS Code, and I opened Chrome as a guest (so no chrome extensions either). Weird how it works on Firefox but not Chrome. Thanks for checking!

Comment: @JimmyTheCode this might help: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/108059